# Magento2 override addto wishlist.phtml

Tags: magento2, overrides, wishlist

```
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>       
        <referenceBlock name="view.addto.wishlist">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module::catalog/product/view/addto/wishlist.phtml</argument>
            </action>
   </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

I have creae same folder structure but file is not override.I have also tried with the block name "product.info.addto" but not changes.

Comment: Are you overriding the template using your theme or by using a custom module

Comment: your query solved?

Comment: @DavaGordon using module

Comment: @RohanHapani no its not working

Comment: You want to override in theme or module?

Comment: Are you sure your module is being loaded in the correct sequence?  so after Magento_Wishlist

Answer (score 1):

> **Try This Way**

**app/code/Vendorename/Modulename/view/frontend/layout**

**catalog_category_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Cookie\Block\RequireCookie" name="require-cookie" template="Magento_Cookie::require_cookie.phtml">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="triggers" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="addToWishlistLink" xsi:type="string">.action.towishlist</item>
                    </argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
            <referenceBlock name="category.product.addto">
                <block class="Vendorename\Modulename\Block\Catalog\Product\ProductList\Item\AddTo\Wishlist"
                       name="category.product.addto.wishlist" as="wishlist" before="compare"
                       template="Vendorename_Modulename::catalog/product/list/addto/wishlist.phtml"/>
            </referenceBlock>
            <referenceContainer name="category.product.list.additional">
                <block class="Magento\Wishlist\Block\AddToWishlist" name="category.product.list.additional.wishlist_addto" template="Magento_Wishlist::addto.phtml" />
            </referenceContainer>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Answer (score 1):

Create the **wishlist.phtml** file in your module,
path:**app/code/{VendorName}/{PackageName}/view/frontend/templates/catalog/product/view/addto**

copy the clone of template from wishlist module’s **wishlist.phtml** file and do your customization.